# How can I create splash screen in Qt5.2 on Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt5

I have created Android application using Qt5.2. It takes a long time to start my application. Qt5 draws black screen by default during application start up.

I want to display company's logo during application start up. How can I do it?

I have found code in QtActivity.java for loading splash screen if it presents. There is a reference in AndroidManifest.xml to splash screen layout. I have tried to create splash.xml in res/layout directory but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug with the splash screen, and here's the ticket for it:
[qt-bugreports](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30652)

If you follow this link you will find a comment ([link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30652?focusedCommentId=223600&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-223600)), which shows a way to display splash screen. (I haven't tested it)

Answer (score 0):

One way<sup>1</sup> to show a splash screen is to edit the `android/AndroidManifest.xml`. Be aware that the Android Manifest editor doesn't provide a GUI to these options<sup>2</sup>, and so it is necessary to use a text editor. The default `AndroidManifest.xml` has a line dealing with splash screens, but it is commented out:

```
<!-- Splash screen -->
<!--
<meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/>
-->
<!-- Splash screen -->
```

Uncomment it, and once you've added application icons to your project via QtCreator's Android Manifest Editor then in your `android` directory there will be `drawable-*` sub-directories. Add your splash images there. The filename should match what comes after `@drawable/` in the resource attribute. Do not specify the file extension in the XML.

Be sure that you add your splash page images to the project directory and not the build directory because the build directory's resources are deleted on each new build.

1. Tested in Qt 5.6
2. In QtCreator 3.6

Thanks to Larpon's [post on Qt's forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/38925/qt-on-android-working-example-of-a-splash-screen/3) for the clues.